# Como converter byte[] para mp3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, áudio

Eu estou escrevendo um app onde eu tenho uma lista de `byte[]` e preciso criar arquivos `.mp3` a partir desses vetores de bytes. Quando solicitado, o app zipa todos esses arquivos em um arquivo `.zip`, porém posteriormente o player não é capaz de reproduzir qualquer um desses áudios. O `byte[]` é originário de uma `openStream()`, onde é transformado num vetor de bytes para que o app possa ter todos os áudios "*in memory*", para que só depois todos sejam transformados em um arquivo.

**Cria arquivo**

```
 private File createFile(String name, byte[] data) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = getContext().openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                             out.write(data);
                             out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return getContext().getFileStreamPath(name);
    }
```

Seria preciso escrever um `header` para o arquivo? Se sim, como?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319372/to-convert-byte-array-to-mp3-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso resolveu meu problema.

```
try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                InputStream stream               = pssu.openStream();
                File mp3                         = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName.toLowerCase());
                OutputStream os                  = new FileOutputStream(mp3);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                int len;
                while ((len = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                audios.add(mp3);

                byteBuffer.close();
                stream.close();
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para `MP3` as coisas funcionam de maneira diferente, arquivos neste formato sofrem encode(codificação), essa codificação permite que os dados raw(bytes) sofra compressão, esta ação vai causar perda de dados, o processo todo demanda entendimento de psicoacústica, processamento digital de sinais, matemática discreta, etc, etc, tudo isso é aplicado para que as perdas durante a codificação tenha a mínima percepção humana possível, portanto meu caro, o `header` não arranha nem a superfície da complexidade para se criar um arquivo `.mp3`, a maneira mais fácil, caso você não tenha interesse em saber a fundo como tudo isso funciona será usar alguma `lib` de terceiro para efetuar o processo de `encode`.

Um arquivo `WAV` é simples, não existe nenhum tipo de codificação e perda dos dados de áudio.

Comment: Eu tinha uma noção que um arquivo mp3 era algo complexo, mas não tanto assim. Me deixou interessado em pesquisar sobre. Sobre o app: estou considerando a possibilidade de mudar o formato para wav